# Opportunity Stage: How to Use Closed Types for Commit Forecast Category

Tags: opportunity, forecast, stagename, stagetype

I have a requirement to change the forecast category we are using to Pipeline, Commit and Omitted Forecast categories alone for all Opp Stages.  This I have changed ok however on testing I noted for Closed/Won with ForecastCategory Commit the IsWon and isClosed fields do not render correct.  This is due to the Open type being auto-assigned to the Stage on changing the ForecastCategory via the UI.
[image]

Type is dependent on the Forecast Category.

I've had a look to see if I could change this via metadata.  If you view the following from the OpportunityStage standardvalue set, if I change the forecastCategory to commit and try to deploy I cannot do so without error. Commit is invalid for Closed/Won
[image]

I tried to change the forecast settings themselves and to add commit to the closedOnly category but this cannot be done.

[image]

I wondered if it's possible to decouple or change the Type to forecastCategory settings on the Opportunity Stage? I'm not sure if it is possible but would like to do so if it can.

Thanks in advance for any tips on how to achieve this.